# java SSLHandshakeException General SSLEngine

Tags: java, ssl

I have a Java server application (loaded with its own server certificate) tries to securely connect with another server (Microsoft - has its server certificate).

They each have the trusted ROOT-CA certs loaded up and I can clearly see on both server. On Java side I loaded root-ca cert in JRE lib/security CA trust store as well as the application's trust store. On the Microsoft server it has root-ca loaded using MMC tool.

During SSL handshake I keep getting this error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem .....
>   ..... Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Root
>   certificate (subject: CN=blah.com, OU=ABC Communications Inc., O=CORP,
>   C=US) of [blah.com] not trusted.

Answer (score 11):

The message says clearly that the root certificate isn't trusted. So you haven't done what you said you did correctly.